# Using managed object context with Dispatch queue in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

According to apple guideline, In order to use managed objects on the main thread, they need to be fetched by a context confined to the main thread only ,Ok thats fine. Below is my code...

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

dispatch_queue_t queue1 = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.AppTask",NULL);
dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue1, ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    workerContext.persistentStoreCoordinator =  del.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSArray *managedObject = [workerContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    dispatch_async(main, ^{
        NSLog(@"%@",managedObject);
        Person *objperson = [managedObject objectAtIndex:0];
        objperson.firstname = @“test”;
        BOOL s = [workerContext save:nil];
        if (s) {
            NSLog(@"done");
        }
    });
});
```

Now as per the guideline I can not modify or save managed object context created by another thread. But above code works fine and modify and save my object without any error. Hence I am able to modify the MO which is fetched by another thread and even I can save MOC which is created by another thread.

Please let me know if my way of doing this is wrong or not because ideally i could not save MOC of Background thread from main thread.

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Its wrong because its thread-unsafe NOT thread impossible to cross threads with contexts and managed objects.

So your trivial example might work some of the time but not all of time in all situations. Sooner or later you are going to get a crash with that pattern.

if you wish to access objects between threads you must send the `objectID` across the thread.

When you create a context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` it creates and manages its own queue.

Your example is expressed better as

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    //set the parent NOT the persistent store coordinator
    workerContext.parentContext =  delegate.managedObjectContext;

    [workerContext performBlock:^{

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
        NSArray *results = [workerContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

        if (results.count) {

            Person *person = [results objectAtIndex:0];
            person.firstname = @“test”;

            BOOL success = [workerContext save:nil];
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"done");
            }

            //you pass ObjectID's NOT managed objects across threads
            NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [person objectID];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                //update your UI here
                Person *thePerson = (Person *)[[delegate managedObjectContext] objectWithID:objectID];
                self.myUIElement.text = person.firstname;

            });
        }

    }];
```

Comment: In order to be consistent, I would have set `[mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{` (where mainManagedObjectContext is initialized with concurrencyType .MainQueueConcurrencyType) instead of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`

Comment: `objectWithID:` should be done on the context's queue, as should the firing of the fault immediately after it. Move those outside of the main queue block.

Comment: @pob true , OP is using the Xcode template stack which provides that implicitly but your change makes for a more correct example.

Comment: @qullish I want the object from the main thread context so I can update UI on main thread. If you recover object via ID while in private queue it will lead to unfulfillable faults and sadness.

Comment: @WarrenBurton, nope. Set a local variable to person.firstname outside of your main queue dispatch block, and set self.myUIElement.text to that local variable inside the block. I can't illustrate this better in a comment.

Comment: @WarrenBurton take a look at https://gist.github.com/quellish/4f59680cc0a679a67128

Comment: @quellish got it. It is the optimal solution for reality but I'm trying to demo to OP how to pass managed object across thread (and that you shouldn't pass MO directly into another thread ) which is why it's written that way.

Comment: @WarrenBurton if that's true, the "update your UI here" part should be using performBlock on that context.

Comment: @WarrenBurton if you don't want to assume a main thread context, you can always create a new one ;) If the root context is a main thread context connected to the persistent store coordinator, accessing it will lose some of the advantages of using nested contexts and queue confinement - the core data IO will be performed on the main thread. Creating a new `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` that's a child of `workerContext` will avoid that. Creating contexts is inexpensive.

Comment: @quellish OP wanted a question answered about the snippet they provided. If you feel so strongly about it, write your own answer. bored now.